# Open email application using expo-intent-launcher

Tags: android, typescript, react-native, android-intent, expo

I am using expo intent launcher to open email application in android devices (open mail only/not compose email)

> https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v43.0.0/sdk/intent-launcher/

and it is working fine using expo-intent-launcher version ~9.1.0,
but after upgrading the expo-intent-launcher to version ~10.0.3
it does not work anymore. because the parameter is changed.

before upgrading

> expo-intent-launcher version ~9.1.0

[image: working version]

after upgrading

> expo-intent-launcher version ~10.0.3

[image: not working version]

Here's the pre defined constant:

ActivityAction: https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/main/packages/expo-intent-launcher/src/IntentLauncher.ts

I got confused how to put this `'android.intent.action.MAIN'` to the parameter because it's not listed in the enums and it doesn't accept string.
[image: intentlauncher]

how can I fix my code so it will work in the newer version?

> expo-intent-launcher version ~10.0.3

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I find the solution by myself.

I was using `Expo SDK 43`,
when upgraded to `Expo SDK 45`, the expo-intent-launcher also upgrdaded to version `~10.2.0`,

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v45.0.0/sdk/intent-launcher

in that version the `activityAction` parameter is now accepting string, instead of only Enums.

So the solution is just upgrade to `Expo SDK 45`.